# using setOnClickListener in a right way

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I'm developing an android app, but I don't have experience with android and I need some help.

I'm going to simplify my code, here is my problem:

I have declared: `TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);`

After, i have a `setOnClickListener`:

```
test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
    // Here i declare: TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test2);
```

When i click `test` for first time it corresponds to `findViewById(R.id.test)` like it should, but when I click for second time it still corresponds `findViewById(R.id.test)`.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: what is that you intend to do?

Comment: when the app starts, i want to pass a string to
findViewById(R.id.test)

after the click, i want to pass this string to a different TextView, to: findViewById(R.id.test2)

Comment: @Joan Your question isn't clear. What do you want? On the first click of your text view you want to write data in 1st text view and on second click on the same text view you want data on your second text view. If this isn't your question then kindly elaborate more.

Comment: i have a answer checker, like:

correct
wrong 1
wrong 2
wrong 3

when I click on correct answer, other data populate the textviews, in a different order.

Comment: What you're doing seems strange and I don't get the point of it, but anyway if you want to change the value of your outer "test" variable from inside the "onClick" method, you need to declare it final or as an instance variable of your Fragment/Activity. And you need to not redeclare it in onClick, otherwise it will be interpreted as another variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's because inside the click listener you're defining a new `TextView`. It's not the same `test` variable.

When you do `TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test2);` inside the click listener, a new `TextView test` variable is defined which is not the same as the one you had defined previously.

If you just want to reassign a value, you should use `test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test2);` inside the onClickListener();

Comment: You are right, but i don't redeclare the same TextView, I declare the example TextView and than: test = example; But the TextView is not updated..